# How to re-label multiple pods in k8s with kubectl label?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Trying to figure out, how to apply new label "app=green" to the pods that are currently marked with "color=green"...

Looks like I could not use "--field-selector" and I do not want to specify name of each pod in "kubectl label" command.

Answer (score 7):

This should work:

```
kubectl label pods --selector=color=green app=green
```

Comment: Thank you , now its so obvious !

```
kubectl label pods --help | grep selector
      --field-selector='': Selector (field query) to filter on, supports '=', '==', and '!='.(e.g. --field-selector key1=value1,key2=value2). The server only supports a limited number of field queries per type.
  -l, --selector='': Selector (label query) to filter on, not including uninitialized ones, supports '=', '==', and '!='.(e.g. -l key1=value1,key2=value2).```

Answer (score 0):

To apply a new label to Pods that are currently labeled with "color=green" without specifying the names of each Pod individually, you can use the `kubectl` command in combination with label selectors. Here's how you can do it:

1. Use a label selector to identify the Pods with the "color=green" label. You can use the `kubectl get pods` command with the `--selector` option to list the Pods that match this label selector:

```bash
kubectl get pods --selector=color=green
```

This command will list all Pods with the "color=green" label.

2. Once you have identified the Pods, you can use the kubectl label command to add the `"app=green"` label to them. You can pipe the list of Pods from the previous step to the kubectl label command like this:

```bash
kubectl get pods --selector=color=green --no-headers | awk '{print $1}' | xargs -I {} kubectl label pod {} app=green
```

Here's what this command does:

- `kubectl get pods --selector=color=green --no-headers` lists the Pods with the "color=green" label without headers.
- `awk '{print $1}'`  extracts the Pod names from the list.
- `xargs -I {} kubectl label pod {} app=green` applies the "app=green" label to each Pod.
  This command will apply the new label "app=green" to all Pods that match the label selector "color=green."

Please be cautious when applying labels to Pods, especially in a production environment, to avoid unintended consequences.